# Installing Kentico 10 at the top level alongside a preexisting site for dev until live

Tags: content-management-system, installation, kentico

I want to use Kentico 10 on a live server that already has a website full of files located at the top level. I want to develop a new site with Kentico alongside this current site. I hope this Kentico site I am building can be unknown to visitors and I can build all the new pages in Kentico and, when I am ready, flip the default home page to go to the Kentico based home page and all the links will work from the top level of the domain like this:

```
www.example.com [home page]
www.example.com/contact
www.example.com/news
```

I installed a test version on a local computer and observed this default setup:

```
http:/localhost/Kentico10
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kentico10
```

With the default file being here: `Kentico10/CMS/Default.aspx`

I am concerned that this doesn't appear to be at the top level. Should I be or does Kentico allow me to set up my top level link structure even if the CMS is contained in those default folders?

Also, if I created a page in Kentico with the address www.example.com/news and I already had a folder in my web directory called "news" with a default or index file in it how does Kentico handle this?

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- Never install a site you intend to do development on in a production environment.
- Set up a new website on your server in IIS and point it to your new directory holding your new Kentico install
- Setup a binding for a specific URL on that website, you will have to have that DNS record pointing to your IP of your production server.
- Ensure your current website already has a URL binding setup for it's current URL otherwise if it is simply bound to * then any requests will be sent to that IIS instance and your new website won't be requested.

Check out this article also on specific step by step instructions on how to setup a site in IIS:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thank you Brenden.

I am concerned about maintaining the availability of some older links/files that wouldn't be incorporated into the new CMS site. If these are at the top level and the base URL now points to a Kentico subfolder then I am not sure this is possible.

Also, would you say the export/import of a Kentico site is complete enough to fully develop all components and content on a development server and then do the import close to launch on the live server expecting a clone of all development work and not be concerned about the transition from 10 to 11 in this process?

Comment: Export/Import isn't much of a solution unless the instances are the same version and hotfix and it's also not a means of deployment IMHO. Use staging or some other deployment method.  I'm not sure how your current setup is but it is possible to have subfolders processed outside of Kentico.  There are some settings in Kentico where you can tell it to ignore.  So what you would do is setup your new site and then move those files/folders over into the new Kentico instance and tell Kentico not to process them in Settings.